# Can I say Merry Christmas and Happy New Year now, on December 14th?

Tags: word-usage

Now is 14th December. Can I now say "Merry Christmas and Happy New Year"?

Comment: This is more a culturally determined thing than something specific of English language, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can say

> Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year!
>   Merry Christmas and all the best in 2017!
>   Merry Christmas! Only 11 days left to shop!

As it is still relatively far away from Christmas, you would usually say this to people you will not see until next year.  If you were to say it to someone and then see them the next day it would be silly.